# keycloak hint email to login page and let keycloak bypass login page if possible

Tags: keycloak

We want this login/signup UX in a mobile app:

1. ask user for email address
2. if the user is registered, check the identity provider used by the specific user and redirect to that idp for login (via appauth).
3. if the user is not registered, send user to keycloak register page

We could build it using our spring boot backend that uses the keycloak API. But I wonder if this is possible without a custom backend? If keycloak does not support it out-of-the-box we would be happy to write a custom SPI or so for it.

The idea is to *not* hint the id provider (as supported to skip the login page via `kc_idp_hint=google`), but we *do* want to hint the `email` address. Keycloak then should find out the used idp (or plain email/pw) and send the user to the respective login/signup system.

Is there any solution like this on the market? How could we build that otherwise?

Comment: What would you do, if your user used multiple idps before? It is not forbidden to use google now, and facebook after, then change your mind and use Sign in with Apple. Which one would you redirect to? Guess it is not the best UX.

Comment: It is a consumer facing app and UX research has shown that todays sign up systems and flows are way to complex. We do not allow using multiple idp (we offer a service flow to change the idp but this is only relevant to <1% of our users).

Comment: Also please note that the question is not about UX-decisions, but only about *how* we can build the said flow.